# Can't get php mailform submit button to refresh current DIV layer only

Tags: php, forms, html, form-submit

I can get the PHP mailform to work correctly.  The problem is I would like the submit button upon validation to not refresh the entire page but just the content div layer.  I have researched various solutions however I am fairly new to PHP so I may be entering the code incorrectly.  The working page can be found at www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website and then by clicking on the contact link.  The actual contact page code is:

```
 <form method="post" id="captcha_form" name="form1" action="mailform.php">
                        <br />
                        <table width="100%" border="0"> 
                          <tr><td rowspan="4" width="125">
 </td> 
                            <td>
 <div id="Imprint3">Name:</div></td>
                                <td width="15"> 
 </td><td><div id="Imprint3">All fields are required.</div></td> 
                          <tr>
                              <td width="150">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="30" value="name" onfocus="if
 (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/></td>
                          <td rowspan="5" colspan="2">
                                <table>
                                  <tr><td width="10"></td><td>
 <div id="Imprint3">Message:</div></td></tr>
                                <tr><td width="10">
 </td>
                                <td width="200"><textarea name="message" id="message" 
 rows="6" cols="25" value="Enter your message" onfocus="if
 (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/><?php echo "</tex" . "tarea>"; ?>                                   
 </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr> 

 <td align="center" colspan="2"> 

 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

 <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset();">
 </td></tr></table>                                 
 </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr> 

 <td valign="top"><div id="Imprint3">Email:</div></td> </tr>
                                <td valign="top">  
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" value="you@email.com" 
 onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"/></td>                              
                            </tr> <tr> 
                              <td width="15"></td>
 <td align="center"> <div style="padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <img src="captcha.php" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="userpass" value="input the above text here" onfocus="if
 (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"></div></td></tr></table></form>
```

and the mailform.php file is as follows:

```
 <?PHP
 session_start();
 try{
$check = new check();
if(!isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    throw new exception('You did not enter an email address.');

if(!isset($_REQUEST['message']))
    throw new exception('You did not enter a message.');

if(!isset($_REQUEST['name']))
    throw new exception('You did not enter a name');

$sender = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$recipient = 'text@text.com';

$subject = 'Regarding Your Portfolio';

if($check->captcha('userpass') == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your captcha is incorrect.');

if($check->spam($sender) == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your email field contains spam.');

if($check->spam($name) == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your name field contains spam.');

if($check->length($sender, 10) == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your email field does not satisfy the minimum character    
count.');

if($check->length($message, 8) == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your message field does not satisfy the minimum character 
count.');

if($check->length($name, 3) == FALSE)
    throw new exception('Your name field does not satisfy the minimum character count.');

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, "From: $name <$sender>" );
include'thankyou.php';

}catch (Exception $E){
die($E->getMessage());

}





class check{

function captcha($field){
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$field])==FALSE){ return false; }
    if($_SESSION['pass'] != $_REQUEST[$field]){ return false; }
    return true;
}

function email($email){
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ return false;}
    return true;
}

function spam($field){
    if(eregi("to:",$field) || eregi("cc:",$field) || eregi("\r",$field) || 
eregi("\n",$field) || eregi("%0A",$field)){ return false; }
    return true;
}

function length($field, $min){
    if(strlen($field) < $min){ return false; }
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

I have replaced my receiving email to text@text.com on this page, but on my site it is my actual email.  Another user helped me a lot with getting this script functioning correctly, but I was wondering if it is possible to get the thankyou.php to refresh into the current div layer and not refresh the entire page.  the line that I want to edit I believe is the: `include 'thankyou.php';` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not possible with php**.
You will have to **use JavaScript** to realize this.

You would be able to send the email without refreshing the page and to load a file in a div.

With **e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com)** and the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function it would look something like this:

```
var msg; // defines variable "msg"

$('#button_ID').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the page from reloading (or default behavior, so the form submit)

msg = $('#input_field_ID').val(); // gets the value of the input field and saves it in variable "msg"

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sendmail.php',
    data: {message : msg}, // posts variable "msg" as "message"
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#yourdivID").load('/thankyou.php'); // loads a file in a div
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('there was an error');
    }
});

});
```

In this example you would be able to get the message in sendmail.php with `$_POST["message"]`

Or use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and serialize your entire form:

```
$.post("/sendmail.php", $("#formID").serialize());
```

Just that you can see how to handle something like this.

Comment: So just to be clear, I can use this javascript in conjuction with my current code be replacing the `include'thankyou.php';` to `$.post["contact.php"], $("#mailform").serialize());` ? Do I call the javascript right on the contact.php page? and then $.post(....); place into my mailform file.  Just a little confused as to the execution of the above scripts.

Comment: That's not how it will work. I just gave you an example of how it would look like if you would solve it with jQuery, because it's not possible with php. You will have to include the jQuery library. Javascript files are included with `<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` or executed with `<script type="text/javascript"> alert('this is a javascript alert'); </script>`. Maybe you want to read into the jQuery documentation to get started, try it on your own and get back to SO if you have further questions: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page